# Wickr 2.6.0-4 Installed but Unable to Open

Tags: 64-bit

I have installed wickr deb installation using the code `sudo gdebi wickr.deb`. But the application won't start. It just remains in the taskbar with the icon glowing and then its gone after a while. The same thing is happening with genymotion.

I have tried reinstalling and restarting. Also have installed using package installer. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after resolving my install dependencies. I was able to locate what was missing after attempting to start the app from terminal:

> wickr-me: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

The fix (from terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

This installed the shared libraries and the plugins. Wickr was then able to open.

Comment: its not working